# html5 autofocus does not work on asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My autofocus attribute is not rendered in the html!

Thats the html defined with razor:

```
   <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name,null, new { autofocus=""})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thats the html from the server generated:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Name">Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="A test needs a title" data-val-length-max="100" data-val-length-min="1" data-val-required="A test needs a title" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I can see no autofocus attribute... I have tried autofocus="autofocus" or autofocus=""

none worked! Why?

Comment: Are you using a custom editor template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This s because you are using EditorFor instead of something specific like TextBoxFor.

If you look at the overloads for EditorFor, there aren't any overload that accept htmlAttributes. The overload you are using actually is taking additionalViewData.

If you change to this it should work (notice I removed the middle null parameter):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { autofocus=""})
```

Comment: and I thought I use TextBoxFor... I used an editor template before... I refactored all just not the EditorFor :P, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`EditorFor` renders an editor template and the overload you've used passes the anonymous object as additional `ViewData`; that doesn't mean that the editor template will actually do anything with it. Try `TextBoxFor` instead, which has an overload accepting additional HTML attributes:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { autofocus = "autofocus" })
```

Alternatively, if you're using a custom editor template, you'll need to do something with the information that you're passing to it; specifically, looking up the `"autofocus"` key in the `ViewData` collection and rendering out the `autofocus` attribute accordingly.